# Html JavaScript if else cancellin

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, prompt

Hey just wondering if you can stop people from closing popup messages that your website displays... not sure if this is possible but basically I'm trying to make a super simple program for ordering stuff but if you exit out of a certain prompt message it skips to the next step... anyway here's the function...

```js
function validateOrder1(){
  var adress = document.getElementById("adress").value;
  var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;

  if (totalPrice < 1){
    alert ("Please buy a pizza!")
    resetOrder()
  }
  else {
    if (document.getElementById("delivery").checked){
      if (adress == 0){
        document.getElementById("adress").value = prompt ("Please enter adress")
        if (phoneNumber == 0){
          document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value = prompt ("Please enter phone number")
          validateOrder2()
        }
        else{
          validateOrder2()
        }
      }
      else{
        if (phoneNumber == 0){
          document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value = prompt ("Please enter phone number")
          validateOrder2()
        }
        else{
          validateOrder2()
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      validateOrder2()
    }
  }
}
```

But since I have the 'else' as moving on to the next stage (which will work when the Phone number/address variables aren't 0) it also just cancels and I cant put an 'else' for when that happens... Not sure exactly how to word that but that was what I came up with..
cheers

Comment: `.value` returns a string.

Comment: Don't use the built-in `prompt` - many browsers actually block it by default. Use your own forms instead.

Comment: The `prompt()` and `alert()` functions in JavaScript should be avoided for exactly the reasons you're discovering: they are very basic and are missing a lot of functionality you probably need. In addition, they can be blocked entirely by some browsers. I suggest replacing them, either with a simple form on your page, or a better modal control written in JavaScript (there are plenty of third-party modal dialog controls you can download, there's bound to be one that meets your needs).

Comment: ok thought that would be the case, I've only just started coding and stuff so don't know much about creating my own forms and stuff but I'll look into it :D